# Tensorflow error loading after pip install

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I've created a conda virtual environment using python 3.7.6. I'm operating on Windows 10 CPU.

Original install failed under pip install tensorflow. pip suggested trying `pip install tensorflow --user`
which worked.

```
pip install tensorflow
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (2.3.0)Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse==1.6.3 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\acsavag\anaconda3\envs\best\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\acsavag\anaconda3\envs\best\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.34.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.1)

Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.9.2 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.12.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.4.1 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.3.3 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\acsavag\anaconda3\envs\best\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing<1.2,>=1.1.1 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\users\acsavag\anaconda3\envs\best\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (49.2.0.post20200714)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\acsavag\anaconda3\envs\best\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5" in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\acsavag\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
```

I've restarted the environment to ensure that's not the issue.

```
pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------------------
absl-py                0.9.0
astunparse             1.6.3
backcall               0.2.0
cachetools             4.1.1
certifi                2020.6.20
chardet                3.0.4
colorama               0.4.3
decorator              4.4.2
gast                   0.3.3
google-auth            1.20.0
google-auth-oauthlib   0.4.1
google-pasta           0.2.0
grpcio                 1.30.0
h5py                   2.10.0
idna                   2.10
ipykernel              5.3.3
ipython                7.16.1
ipython-genutils       0.2.0
jedi                   0.17.1
jupyter-client         6.1.6
jupyter-core           4.6.3
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.2
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.Markdown               3.2.2
numpy                  1.18.5
oauthlib               3.1.0
opt-einsum             3.3.0
pandas                 1.1.0
parso                  0.7.0
pickleshare            0.7.5
pip                    20.1.1
prompt-toolkit         3.0.5
protobuf               3.12.4
pyasn1                 0.4.8
pyasn1-modules         0.2.8

Pygments               2.6.1
python-dateutil        2.8.1
pytz                   2020.1
pywin32                227
pywrap                 0.1.0
pyzmq                  19.0.1
requests               2.24.0
requests-oauthlib      1.3.0
rsa                    4.6
scipy                  1.4.1
setuptools             49.2.0.post20200714
six                    1.15.0
tensorboard            2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.7.0
tensorflow             2.3.0
tensorflow-estimator   2.3.0
termcolor              1.1.0
tornado                6.0.4
traitlets              4.3.3
urllib3                1.25.10
wcwidth                0.2.5
Werkzeug               1.0.1
wheel                  0.34.2
wincertstore           0.2
wrapt                  1.12.1
```

TensorFlow and its subsequent dependencies are successfully installed

```
import tensorflow

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1 in 
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in 
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in 
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in 
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in 
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acsavag\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I've tried to trace back the errors in the code to determine the first true breakpoint, but unfortunately all dependencies that are being searched for are in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest MSVC 2019 64 bit and it worked.

Lot's of github issues have the same error question, and many just referenced about 10 ticket clones.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36167 <- this one lists 4 possible scenarios this issue arises and working down it like a checklist helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the TensorFlow library file manually and reinstall it using pip